# C#, alignment in Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a problem to output aligned text in a Textbox. The output has not the expected table-look. 'Hd' and '%' are not in the same column (if amount of digits differ).

```
//--- estimate bet / raise range ---
fHands = (double)nHandsRaise / 1326;
strTemp = fHands.ToString("P");

tb_RangeInfo.Text = String.Format("{0,-4}", "R:")
                          + String.Format("{0,6}", nHandsRaise) 
                          + String.Format("{0,-6}", " Hd")
                          + String.Format("{0,6}", strTemp) + "\r\n";

//--- estimate call / check range ---
fHands = (double)nHandsCall / 1326;
strTemp = fHands.ToString("P");
tb_RangeInfo.Text += String.Format("{0,-4}", "C:") 
                           + String.Format("{0,6}", nHandsCall)
                           + String.Format("{0,-6}", " Hd")
                           + String.Format("{0,6}", strTemp) + "\r\n";

//--- estimate fold range ---
fHands = (double)nHandsFold / 1326;
strTemp = fHands.ToString("P");
tb_RangeInfo.Text += String.Format("{0,-4}", "F:") 
                           + String.Format("{0,6}", nHandsFold)
                           + String.Format("{0,-6}", " Hd")
                           + String.Format("{0,6}", strTemp);
```

Comment: Are you using a fixed-width font? If not then of course using the same number of characters won't ensure alignment.

Comment: By the way, why on Earth are you concatenating multiple calls to `String.Format`? That's just silly. You can format as many values as you want with a single call.  Any research on that method would show you that. Also, concatenating a literal to the end of that is silly too. The format specifier can contain literal characters too. Finally, don't keep setting the `Text` of a `TextBox` over and over. Create the full text first and then set the `Text` once.

Comment: My fist try was a single call of String.Forma(), but cause it doesn't work I try several implementations.  My textbox is designed as:  <TextBox x:Name="tb_RangeInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="138" Height="60" Margin="210,15.2,32,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Range info" UndoLimit="10" FontFamily="GenericMonospace" Background="#FFFFFDD2" Foreground="Black" IsUndoEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Problem solved!    I changed to FontFamily="Lucida Console" in the designer and it works